# Error when adding multiselect attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, collection

I am trying to add a multi select attribute with a collection ( custom created ) , the attribute has been added successfully but when I edit collection to fill this new field value it shows an error `Failed to load node  from config`

Comment: maybe you should show the code you used to add the attribute? or you did it via the UI?

Comment: I did it with UI